How to use Fakerjs in Apidog
I'm using Fakerjs in Apidog for testing. In the body in JSON, I am trying to generate an email with the domain "gmail.com". According to the Fakerjs documentation, this is done like this:
"email": "{% faker internet.email({ firstName: 'Jeanne', lastName: 'Doe' }) %}".
But this doesn't work, the output is:
"email": "objectObject.Botsford77@yahoo.com".
Help please.
In Apidog, the spelling is slightly different from what is described in the Fakerjs documentation. For example, in Fakerjs, it looks like this:
faker.internet.email({ firstName: 'Jeanne', lastName: 'Doe', provider: 'example.fakerjs.dev' }).
As you can see, the semantics are slightly different. But the essence remains the same.

"email": "{% faker internet.email('Jeanne', 'Doe', 'example.fakerjs.dev') %}"


While you supplied one possible example, please elaborate on what exactly can be expected of this particular example, what limits the user may need to take into account and elaborate on possible alternative ways (e.g. compatibility or problems with different protocols, web tech etc..)

Sorry, not an Apidog developer, just replied to the question I knew the answer for.
